# Should I turn around header and footer when I use landscape?

Tags: tables, header-footer, landscape

I have a general question about layout, thus I don't deliver a MWE yet (if you want one, please tell me).

In my appendix, I use a lot of landscaped pages for longtables. The tables are several pages long. At the moment, header and footer still are in portrait format.

Should I twist the header & footer into landscape format when I use landscaped tables or should I keep it in portrait format?

Please give an explanation why/ why not.

Comment: This is not really on-topic - maybe better suited to the graphic design site? If you wanted to know how to twist (or not twist) them, that's on topic, but whether to do so or not is not really anything to do with TeX. And I'm not sure there is a 'correct' answer to this. Probably the answer is 'It depends'. For whatever it is worth, I would not twist them. It makes it difficult to find the right page as page numbers are no longer in their usual places.

Comment: It's a design choice, when writing lscape I chose to keep headers and footers in portrait orientation, which I still think is the most natural (and common) but there are certainly cases where moving the page number to landscape works as well.

Comment: If your work will be printed: Imagine the paper/report/book printed in your hand, and now turn over to the landscape page.

Comment: IMHO the only reason (good reason) for turn around headers and footers when you use landscape page orientation is when you create a full landscape document. If the main orientation is vertical, then no matters if you have a lot of pages in landscape orientation, you should keep the vertical orientation of headers and footers.